# Чат на Java, выводящий на страницу новые сообщения в репльном времени

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee, soap

Зачем это? Просто учусь на таких вот задачках.

В общем. Один пользователь мгновенно получает сообщения от другого, причём без обновления страницы, а сообщения с данными отправителя загружаются в БД с историей чата, чтобы можно было позже выгрузить. С БД я разберусь. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю, как реализовать получение сообщений без обновления веб-страницы и куда выгружать сообщения (в таблицу или как ещё...)

Comment: Масса примеров чата на firebase или socket.io - откройте посмотрите пример и будет ясно всё. Контент страницы можно динамически обновлять без перезагрузок

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы получать сообщения без обновления страницы вам нужны [вебсокеты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Это такой двунаправленный способ коммуникации, когда сервер может посылать запросы клиенту. Современные браузеры поддерживает этот протокол. В java вэбсокеты представлены спецификацией [jsr356](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356).

Следующие сервера приложений имеет поддержку вебсокетов:

- Tomcat 7.0.47+
- Jetty 9.1+
- GlassFish 4.1+
- WebLogic 12.1.3+
- Undertow 1.0+
- WildFly 8.0+
- и др.

Можно реализовать как на [JavaEE7](https://blog.openshift.com/how-to-build-java-websocket-applications-using-the-jsr-356-api/), так и с использованием [спринга](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html)